# Reseed a newly created table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have create a new table on SQL Server 2008.

This table has an identity column, defined like this:

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

However when I insert any data, the first record starts from 0, instead of 1.

I want the records to start from 1. Why does this not work?

If I delete the record and reseed it to 0, it works.

```
Delete from [tablename]
DBCC CHECKIDENT('[tablename]', RESEED, 0)
```

However it does not work on newly created tables.

Even if I delete and reseed a newly created table, it still starts adding record from 0, instead of 1.

Can you anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen the syntax of [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)? Change that 0 to 1 and you're set.

Comment: Thanks - But I am calling a delete before dbcc checkident. As far as I know this should reseed from newvalue + 1. Moreover why does Identity(1,1) not work?

Comment: The delete doesn't reseed the value. Only TRUNCATE does the reseed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql), but counter-intuitive:

> Current identity value is set to the new_reseed_value. If no rows have
>   been inserted into the table since the table was created, or if all
>   rows have been removed by using the TRUNCATE TABLE statement, the
>   first row inserted after you run DBCC CHECKIDENT uses new_reseed_value
>   as the identity. Otherwise, the next row inserted uses
>   new_reseed_value + the current increment value.

It was acknowledged as a bug (on the now-defunct Microsoft Connect site), but not one that will be fixed. Workarounds include avoiding using the `RESEED` option on newly-created tables, or to use a higher value that will work in all cases but may result in gaps. Gaps are all but inevitable with `IDENTITY` anyway. If you must do the reseed, wrap it in a check like:

```
IF EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.identity_columns 
    WHERE 
        [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T1', N'U')
        AND last_value IS NOT NULL
)
BEGIN
    DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.T1', 'RESEED', 0)
END;
```

To be clear, creating a table and adding a row will result in the first identity value being used:

```
-- Tested on SQL Server 2008 SP3 CU8
-- build 10.0.5828
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1 (id int IDENTITY(1, 1));
INSERT dbo.T1 DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT id FROM dbo.T1 AS t;
```

[image: Id 1]

Comment: Thanks.However can you explain why I need to reseed though. Why does specifying Identity(1,1) not start the first record from 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are using 0 for you the new_reseed_value in your DBCC CHECKIDENT command.

See this section from [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

> Current identity value is set to the new_reseed_value. If no rows have been inserted to the table since it was created, or all rows have been removed by using the TRUNCATE TABLE statement, **the first row inserted after you run DBCC CHECKIDENT uses new_reseed_value as the identity.** Otherwise, the next row inserted uses new_reseed_value + the current increment value.

Comment: Thanks. yes I think this was what I doing wrong. However can you explain why I need to reseed though. Why  does specifying Identity(1,1) not start the first record from 1.